# Keyboard shortcut to change indentation of several lines in Python

Tags: python

I have become more than a little afraid of asking questions here, but I tried searching the site for this question and I cannot find anything even remotely related.

I wonder if/how I can ''mass align'' several lines of code at the same time, when for example I forgot to start with a while-loop and want to quickly put the rest of the code in that loop. I'm sure there are other situations as well, but this one is bothering me.

I think I've seen someone do it in a video once, but that was just automatic behavior and not part of the video subject matter. I have to say I'm generally interested in ''hotkey behavior'' by coders as I played Age of Empires 2 online in the past.

Anyway, the point is that when I select this:

```
while True:
flag = hero.findFlag("green")
if flag:
hero.pickUpFlag(flag)
```

the only thing I can change with one mouse action is this:

```
while True:
    flag = hero.findFlag("green")
if flag:
hero.pickUpFlag(flag)
```

Again, I think I've seen an advanced coder forgetting something like a loop and then mass-correct it with a bunch of key hits. And I have no idea how to do this other than just doing it line by line. If you add a ''code sample'' here on Stackoverflow I also always have to correct every line manually.

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: A built-in one on the site Codecombat.com, but I've also used other places. Do you want me to check in Pycharm? I'm just a beginner

Comment: This is not a Python setting and depends entirely on what editor / IDE your are using — so look in the Help or documentation of whatever that is.

Comment: generally marking the lines and hitting TAB may work in most windows based IDEs. For online code editors ... who knows. Shift-TAB unindents the selection.

Comment: Actually in Pycharm, I can select everything and with Tab it just works the way I want it to. Maybe it's just an unsupported feature on Codecombat.com and Sololearn.com

Comment: OK good to know it depends on the editor. Cheers, guys

Comment: @PatrickArtner Thanks a lot for the unindentation shortcut. I probably should've known about the identation one, but I wasn't familiar with the other and I'm sure I will come in handy

Answer (score 3):

This solely depends on the text editor/IDE you are using. You can use an autoformatter, or the indentation shortcuts of your text editor. In vim for example, one would do `gg =G` to indent the entire file accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Codecombat and PyCharm lets you change the indentation of multiple lines by highlighting the lines and using the `Tab` key. You can un-indent using `Shift + Tab`.

Comment: Thanks, it works indeed, the answer is much simpler than expected

Answer (score 1):

For future reader, in case if you want to do indent in VS code in Mac OS X, try below steps:

Select multiple line and  Press `Command + ]`

and for de-indent, select multiple line and press `Command + [`

For windows OS:
after select multiple line,
Indent: `Ctrl+]`
De-indent: `Ctrl+[`